# vba error handling with absence of the required column

Tags: vba

I Need to write universal macro to Count conditionally columns in different tables.

Problem is that every table can contain different number of columns.

Therefore, if the required columns does not exist, the error appears.

In this case i would like to apply error handler, which will write in the column "null".

I try the code below, it works, the error does not appear and macro continue to run, but the cells in the columns remains empty, without "null"
What is the Problem? Maybe there is more optimal way to manage it?

```
Function Section800_error()
    Dim zelle As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim posMonitoring As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim intLastRow As Integer
    On Error GoTo Handler
    With Sheets("ICS Table")
       Set zelle = .Cells.Find("800_Section", lookat:=xlPart)
       posMonitoring = zelle.Column
       intLastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
       For i = 2 To intLastRow
          If .Cells(i, posMonitoring).Value < 1 Or .Cells(i, posMonitoring).Value > 10 Then
               Sheets("Section_errors").Cells(i, 8) = "err700"
          Else
               Sheets("Section_errors").Cells(i, 8) = "no"             
          End If
       Next i
    End With
Exit Function

Handler:

    For i = 2 To intLastRow  
        Sheets("Section_errors").Cells(i, 8).Value = "null"
    Next i           
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

a possible correction

```
Function Section800_error()
    Dim zelle As Range
    Dim i As long
    Dim posMonitoring As Integer
    Dim intLastRow As Integer
    With Sheets("ICS Table")
        Set zelle = .Cells.Find("800_Section", lookat:=xlPart)
        If zelle Is Nothing Then
            For i = 2 To intLastRow
                Sheets("Section_errors").Cells(i, 8).Value = "null"
            Next i
        Else
            posMonitoring = zelle.Column
            intLastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
            For i = 2 To intLastRow
                If .Cells(i, posMonitoring).Value < 1 Or .Cells(i, posMonitoring).Value > 10 Then
                    Sheets("Section_errors").Cells(i, 8) = "err700"
                Else
                    Sheets("Section_errors").Cells(i, 8) = "no"
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: One remark: Always use `long` for row/column numbers to avoid overflows.

Comment: @Elena, could you then validate the solution ?

Comment: @Elena you have had a lot of people help you on Stack Overflow and have yet to give anyone any credit for their efforts. Notice to the left of peoples solutions is a **check mark**. When someone's solution works for you, **you should mark the solution as valid** by clicking on that **check mark** which notifies future viewers what worked and gives credit to people who spent their time helping you.